# .Net Application Cache in Cloud Environment

Tags: .net, caching, enterprise-library, cloud

I'm using the Enterprise Application Block and my application is hosted in a Cloud Environment. I was wondering what else I need to do with my implementation to make it as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the cloud, where everything is naturally distributed, you will definitely want to look into having a distributed cache solution.

In-memory application cache will not be able to handle distributed environment very well.

Imagine this scenario:

- request 1 comes in
- server 1 is processing the request
- in memory cache on server 1 is primed and filled in with the popular data
- request 2 comes in, asking for the same data
- server 2 is processing the request
- in memory cache on server 2 is yet primed again and filled in with the popular data

as you can see here, we're getting 2 misses to prime the cache. You will need a dedicated distributed cache server where it'll service all the cache requests.